# C program prints twice a message

Tags: c, debugging, fork

I've created the following little program, I'm going crazy on understanding why it prints "HelloHello" instead of just "Hello". And even strangely if I write 'printf ( "Hello\n" )' instead it works as expected.

I'm running Linux Mint 16 Petra.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main () {

    printf ( "Hello" );

    switch ( fork () ) {

        case 0:
            exit(0);

        case -1:
            exit(1);

        default:
            exit(0);

    }

}
```

Comment: This is caused by buffering of `stdout`. Use `fflush(stdout)` before the call to `fork()`.

Comment: @RSahu: Better `fflush(0)`, to flush all output-streams.

Comment: @Deduplicator, I didn't know that. Thanks for the lesson of the day :)

Comment: Thank you all, you saved me an headache... damn C!